# Is it possible to get a list of all values that can be returned in a web service

Tags: c#, java, json, web-services, rest

Is it possible to get a list of all values that can be returned in a web service?

I am looking at APIs from Open Weather Map doing these 2 calls:

- http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=paarl
- http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

If you look at the JSON returned you will see that for Paarl there are extra properties in `main` like `grnd_level` and `sea_level` that London doesn't return.

Is it possitbly for me to see all that values that can be returned and not just the values that are returned.  Maybe I search for another region and then it returns other values that I am not aware of.  I can't always go and check the JSON results.

I would like to cater for most/almost all scenarios.

Comment: Not really.  If it was a SOAP service, and there was a WSDL file, maybe.   This looks like a REST service.  Doesn't the API owner provide documentation?

Comment: Nope no decent documentation. Go and check at http://openweathermap.org/API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[API](http://openweathermap.org/API) does not provide exact props, so it might be different for cities and be based on station too. As for me, you should choose properties you wanna see in your program and display them, no need to show all the possible data.